# Angular button click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and I don't know how to do this kind of action. I have these buttons:

```
<button *ngIf="entryControlEnabled && !gateOpen" class="bottomButton red" (click)="openGate()">Open</button>
<button *ngIf="entryControlEnabled && gateOpen" class="bottomButton green" (click)="closeGate()">Close</button>
```

And In .ts file I have this:

```
if (data.IoNumber == config.IoNumberGates) {
 if (data.IoStatus == "DetectorDeactivated") {
  this.gateOpen = true;
  } else {
  this.gateOpen = false;
  }
}
```

I want to change `data.IoStatus == "DetectorDeactivated"` to `data.IoStatus == "DetectorActivated"`

I want to illustrate what I mean:

```
openGate(){
 this.data.IoStatus == "DetectorActivated"
}

closeGate(){
 this.data.IoStatus == "DetectorDeactivated"
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: You could simplify this code so much

Comment: your `openGate()` and `closeGate()` are not performing anything since you are only evaluating a boolean expression. Did you mean this deliberately?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to simplify the code. There is more to it, but for demo purpose and to show what I want I simplified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to switch variable `this.gateOpen` to true or false and `this.gateOpen`, `openGate` and `closeGate` belongs to same component. Your functions should look like this.

```
openGate(){
 // this.data.IoStatus == "DetectorActivated";
 // it's wrong, this is comparison not assignement
 this.data.IoStatus = "DetectorActivated";
}

closeGate(){
 // this.data.IoStatus == "DetectorDeactivated";
 // it's wrong, this is comparison not assignement
 this.data.IoStatus = "DetectorDeactivated";
}
```

Hope it helps

```
if (data.IoNumber == config.IoNumberGates) {
    if (data.IoStatus == "DetectorDeactivated") {
      this.gateOpen = true;
    } else {
      this.gateOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Make sure this code runs on correct event, in your case it should be click event or something. Else just directly change the `this.gateOpen` variable in functions like this.

```
openGate(){
    this.gateOpen = true;
}

closeGate(){
    this.gateOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: if (data.IoNumber == config.IoNumberGates) {
        if (data.IoStatus == "DetectorDeactivated") {
          this.gateOpen = true;
        } else {
          this.gateOpen = false;
        }
    }

Make sure this code runs on correct event, in your case button click

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use a slide / switch toggle. Below I am using Angular Material Slide Toggle.

View:

```
<mat-slide-toggle #approve (change)="toggle($event)" [labelPosition]="'before'">
            {{approve.checked? "Detector Activated": "Detector Activate"}}</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Component:

```
toggle(event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
  console.log('Toggle fired');
  if(event.checked)
     this.data.IoStatus = "DetectorActivated";
  else
     this.data.IoStatus = "DetectorActivated";
}
```

Comment: Well I can't change code so much because i'm working on colleague's code until he come back.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you really want to achieve from your question. I created a dummy app on StackBlits, check it out [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/gateswitch-jon-levi)